# Fit borders to "real" image, cut of white borders SpriteKit objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am learning Spritekit right now and I want to detect a collision between two images.
Just a fun picture as an example : [image]

The image is still a rectangle. How can I fit it that this rectangle will fit to the original face?  I don't want the collision early when it hits the rectangle of the Image, I want it to collide when it actually hits the black lines of the face.

I hope you can understand my problem.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. You probably want to set up your `SKPhysicsBody` to be a path around your `SKSpriteNode`. For example, something like the following is close:

   ```
   UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(-40, -22, 80, 39)];
   node.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:path.CGPath];
   ```

   That's probably not quite right, so feel free to tweak those values, but hopefully it illustrates the idea: Come up with a path that defines your boundary, and then set the `physicsBody` accordingly.

   If you want to see the physics outlines, set `showsPhysics` on the `SKView`.
2. You probably want to mask your image so that the corners of the image are transparent (i.e. have an alpha of zero):

   [image]

   So, when that's on a colored background it looks like:

   [image]

   By masking the corners, you don't have to worry about the white corner covering up something else on the scene.

Comment: Can i somehow make the borders of the actual physics body visible?

Comment: @Robin - Turn on `showsPhysics` on the `SKView`. Note, when I did that, I noticed my `path` wasn't quite right, so I updated it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If its an image thats got white borders all around it, u can edit it in Preview and use Alpha to get rid of all of the white around it.

I think in that case, the sprite's collision method will collide with the black lines.

Comment: Could you explain it maybe? I added a screen of the pic when i open it in Preview, I just don't know alpha?

Comment: So in the image, click on the 2nd button (left of the one thats highlighted blue in the image). Thats the alpha button. Next click on an area of white outside ur smiley face, and drag the mouse a bit until the white u want to delete is highlighted. Press backspace. If ur satisfied with the results, press save. If not, you can always undo.